# @for loop variable name printed instead of contents in tabbing environment

Tags: macros, indentation, loops, tabbing

I'm trying to automatically generate some indented lines using the `tabbing` environment and a `@for` loop. For some reason, this results in the for loop printing the name of the iteration variable over and over rather than the contents. What am I doing wrong?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
a \= b\\
\> c\\
\makeatletter
\@for\ij:=abc,def\do{\>\ij{}\\}
\makeatother
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hackish: try `\@for\ij:=abc,def\do{\expandafter\>\ij{}\\}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table cells create groups, so any non-global assignment is lost when TeX goes to another cell (here, when you use `\>` to go to the next column or `\\` to the next row).  `\@for` does a local assignment to the loop variable, so it is naturally lost when the table cell ends.  You see the "name" of the loop variable being printed because you chose `\ij`, whose standard definition prints the Dutch digraph "ĳ".  If you had used `\ii` (or anything not defined) you would get an error.

If the loop variable is the very first thing after the `\>`, you can cheat and expand the loop variable before the table cell ends with `\expandafter`.  This won't work (without adaptation) if there's anything before the loop variable:

```
\@for\ii:=abc,def\do{\expandafter\>\ii{}\\}
```

You can also assign to a global variable before ending the table cell, then you can have the global variable appear anywhere.

```
\@for\ii:=abc,def\do{\global\let\jj=\ii  \> something \jj{}\\}
```

But I'd recommend using a looping function that doesn't use a looping variable.  For example, `expl3's` `\clist_map_inline:nn` (here renamed as `\ListLoop`):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \ListLoop \clist_map_inline:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
a \= b\\
\> c\\
\ListLoop{abc,def}{\>#1\\}
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

The first argument is the list to iterate, and the second is the code to execute at each iteration, in which `#1` is the current item (or `##1` of you are using `\ListLoop` inside a definition).

Comment: Many thanks for the in-depth explanation, it's very appreciated.